# Google sheets Formula needed for counting and combining data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I need help with a project and I am fairly new to doing formulas.

I have two tabs in a sheet. One contains all items that I have in stock and the other contains what was bought and the quantity.

Tab 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEUSP.png)

Tab 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR7v0.png)

Basically I need a formula that is going to count the number of times an item has appeared in A in Tab 2 and place it in the appropriate cell in column B in Tab 1.

And it would look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp24d.png)

I would really appreciate your help and I am open to all suggestions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF` to count if the value matches, an `ARRAYFORMULA` to let this apply to all values in the range:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A2:A, A2:A13))
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! The answer was actually really simple and here my brain wanted to complicate things and I tried difficult formulas when in reality it's a simple problem :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Sarapanda You're welcome. Also, remember that you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers that you consider helpful. This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.